# Middleware format response

Tags: c#, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, middleware

Using .NET Core, C#.

I added middleware on startup so I can format error responses << This works! But unfortunately, I somehow seem to have lost the response when they are not error responses.  Do I have to read the response and then write the response back?

```
public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
    {
        var body = context.Response.Body;

        using (var newBody= new MemoryStream())
        {
            context.Response.Body = newBody;

            await _next(context);
            if (context.Response.StatusCode != 200 && context.Response.StatusCode != 206)
            {
                context.Response.Body = body;
                updatedBody.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
                var msg= new StreamReader(updatedBody).ReadToEnd();

                if (msg.Length > 0) {
                    context.Response.ContentType = _messageParser.GetFormat();
                    var response = _messageParser.MakeItPretty(msg);
                    await context.Response.WriteAsync(response);
                }
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: You are missing an ELSE when StatusCode is not 200 nor 206.

Comment: @jdweng that should be an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because You are disposing `newBody` so when response is not an error response then whole response body gets disposed and lost. You could create `else` statement and copy response to original `body`:

```
if (context.Response.StatusCode != 200 && context.Response.StatusCode != 206)
{
    ...
}
else
{
    context.Response.Body = body;
    newBody.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
    await newBody.CopyTo(context.response.Body);
}
```

Or my personal preference is to create custom ErrorResult which implements IActionResult or inherits ObjectResult where You can format message using your object instead of string:

```
public class ErrorResult : ObjectResult
{
    public ErrorResult(MyError error)
        : base(error)
    {
        StatusCode = 400;
    }

    public override Task ExecuteResultAsync(ActionContext context)
    {
        var messageParser = context.HttpContext.RequestServices.GetService(typeof(IMessageParser));
        ContentTypes.Add(messageParser.GetFormat());

        <other modifications>

        return base.ExecuteResultAsync(context);
    }
```

and then return it in controllers

```
...
return new ErrorResult(new MyError(...));
...
```

Comment: Thank you!

Am I right in thinking that my approach could be quite costly? By using, " await newBody.CopyTo(context.response.Body);" I am copying the original response and so if it's a huge bit of data, I am duplicating it in memory?

Comment: I like the custom ErrorResult approach.  Thank you

Comment: I settled on using the custom ErrorResult approach as it's a lot more lightweight.